# How to know if JSP has some unclosed tags?

Tags: java, jsp

I have to migrate around 500 JSPs from tag library 1 to tag library 2. For most of the tags I have one to one mapping with me. So for me, easiest way is to write a program to do this job.

While writing this program, unclosed tags in the JSPs are creating issues. For that I want a utility which can tell me in advance, if there are some unclosed tags. Are there some utilities available for this?

Thanks

Comment: Unclosed tags, as in unclosed HTML tags or simply taglib tags?

Comment: Have you tried something like http://validator.w3.org/ ??

Comment: You have to use validators :[here](http://validator.w3.org/)  like that you are going to have not closed tags underlined in yellow

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing a program for migration, why not write a program for validation as well?
Steps could be

1. Going through the JSP file as a text, identifying `<` and `>` and anything within
   them as a tag. (only if `<` ends with `/>` it should not be considered)
2. Identify `</` and `>` and anything within them as end tag
3. Store all the opened and closed tags with a count
   (You might use a hashmap for that.)
4. In the end, check the count of opened and closed tags.